# Unity LookAt function breaks gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d game and want to make bullets aim at and than move to the player. i am using the LookAt function for the aiming part, but the problem is that it just makes my object invisible.
the code is:

```
rigidbdy = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
transform.LookAt(target.transform);
rigidbdy.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(force, 0));
```

i have tried moving it to an empty gameobject, which fixed the invisibility, but the object doesnt look at the player.
i am not getting eny errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens probably because LookAt() rotates the object in 3D space but you work with a 2D environment, try to use one of the 2D rotation solutions. For example:

```
var dir = target.transform - transform.position;
var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```